# How to sync the computer local data in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: python, synchronization, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to create a system that works in the background on the computer and when I turned on the computer it would send the time that the computer was turned on to a spreadsheet on Google SpreadSheet and when it were turned off It also sync the time that the computer was turned off in the spreadsheet of Google Spreadsheet.

How could I create this?

Comment: When you can catch these moments into a csv-file, then you can write a script that uploads the file to Google Drive (Google Apps Script or processes it immediately) and import it into Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Apps Script** will let you create a "web app", and you can pass params to it. There are good docs on how to do this, should be quick and easy way compared to using GData style spreadsheet API. (No Auth2 etc)